# Difference between subjunctive and conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions, subjunctives

I am a Spanish speaker. Recently I found the following sentence in linguee.com:

> I had never been married and I was sure that I would never find anyone who **would love** and accept me, especially...

I also found the following one:

> This amendment cannot be accepted as it would exclude from the Directive anyone who **had taken** a distance-learning course...

Now, in Spanish we would say the second sentence just as it is written here with "had taken" in subjuntive. Can someone explain why the first sentence uses the conditional "would love" instead of the past subjuntive "anyone who loved me" just like in the other sentence? Or why the second sentence is not written "anyone who would have written"?

What is the difference between them? They are both hypothetical, aren't they?

Comment: You will also hear native speakers saying *as it would exclude anyone who **took** a distance-learning course*.

Comment: That's perfectly valid in spanish too. What is not valid is the conditional.

Comment: *I was sure that I **would** (past tense of **will**) never find anyone.*  That is future-in-past.  It is not a hypothetical.

Comment: What about "it would exclude", is that a future-in-past too or not? Is that the difference?

Comment: In the sentence using **it would exclude** it is a conditional, not a future-in-past. The sentence can be understood as *if accepted, the amendment would exclude ...*  **would** is used modally there

Comment: Ok, I get it. Now, I just heard on tv this: "you wouldn't have a staffer who wouldn't have resigned" and I have the same problem, why not "who hadn't resigned"?

Comment: That sentence is not crystal clear without context and even context might not make it clear. The sequence of tenses and the negatives are confused. It's nearly gibberish. Was it a (leading) question? Or  a statement?

Comment: A statement. Just add "I know" at the beginning. She was comparing her conversation partner to Trump who had done nothing after someone in his staff who had insulted Maccain refused to resign.

Comment: It's still unclear. Without listening to the full conversation, it's hard to tell what she means by the first **have**.   Hire?  Keep on staff?  Is now on your staff? And the second "who wouldn't have resigned" seems to be a hypothetical of some kind.  Prepending **I know**, perhaps she meant **I know you wouldn't keep on staff someone who would not have been willing to hand in their resignation (under those circumstances)**.  If so, the *irrealis* there suggests the speaker is saying "Surely that person must have offered to resign since you would not retain a person who had refused to do so"

Comment: I have reviewed the conversation. She said exactly: "you wouldn't have a staffer who wouldn't have resigned by this point." Maybe the key is  "by this point"

Comment: It's not a matter of knowing exactly what she said, but a matter of knowing the context in which the statement was made.

Comment: I had never been married and I was sure that I would never find anyone who would love and accept me, especially...= I have never married and am sure I will not find anyone who will love and accept me. Would=past tense of will, here.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

The difference is the time frame during which an action occurs with respect to a hypothetical point in time.

### Details

For purposes of explanation, let's define a reference point in time, then the time frame during which the expressions in question take place.

**For the first case:**

> I had never been married and I was sure that I would never find anyone
>   who **would love** and accept me, especially...

**Reference point in time:** the time of "having found someone", hypothetically

**Time frame of phrase in question:** "who would..." then refers to anytime in the future after that hypothetical reference point.

**For the second case:**

> This amendment cannot be accepted as it would exclude from the
>   Directive anyone who **had taken** a distance-learning course...

**Reference point in time:** the time "the amendment had excluded", hypothetically

**Time frame of phrase in question:** "who had taken..." then refers to anytime in the past before that hypothetical reference point.

Comment: What about this sentence that I heard the other day on tv: " I know you wouldn't have a staffer who wouldn't have resigned" Meaning If you were Trump you wouldn't keep someone in your staff who in that case wouldn't have (or had not) resigned. Why "wouldn't have" instead of "had not?" I'd say the reference point is "If you were Trump (now)" and the time frame of the phrase in question is earlier than now "the staffer  had not resigned" so she should have said "who had not resigned" Where am I wrong?

Comment: Or maybe I am wrong about the meaning of the sentence. What do you think?

Comment: I was sure that I would never find anyone who would love = in the present< I am sure that I will never find anyone who loves me.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the word *would* in the wiktionary and it gave me the solution. There it says that *would* can be, besides the conditional, the subjunctive of *will*. This means it is the subjunctive future and it can be translated directly into spanish and fits still better than the subjunctive past. I had not realized this because in spanish that tense is used only in the bible.

Comment: You have misunderstood the use of would "as subjunctive" in English. That use is for sentences like: Would that I were rich. Would that he were telling the truth. Today, that is very literary and would only be spoken by highly literate people.Spanish in English, takes a capital s.And actually, in Spanish, those would be Ojalá que fuera rico. For example.

Comment: @Lambie I was taught that “Ojalá que” translates as “If only” or “I wish”. I’ve only ever seen “Would that” in dusty classics from way back in English Lit.

Comment: @StephenS Don't confuse directionality. If you are going from English to Spanish, Would that x were etc. is Ojalá. Of course, if you are going from Spanish to English, it is in fact what's in dusty classics, today expressed as I wish or If only. Yeah? :) But re this answer: would is the subjunctive of will means what I explained and the poster did not know that.